# The columns are disarrayed in pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

[image: jupyter notebook image]

The code is to build a pd.crosstab with Titanic dataset in Seaborn. The column sums in the output table look disarrayed.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

bin = [0,15,100]
titanic["adult"] = pd.cut(titanic.age, bin, labels=["kid","adult"])
pd.crosstab(titanic.survived, titanic.adult, normalize=True, margins=True)
```

I expected to have `0.116246 / 0.883754 / 1.000000`, but it gives `0.883754 / 0.116246 / 1.000000` in the last row where the column sums should be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flipping/reversal of totals is simply due to the presence of NaN values in the original `age` column, and subsequently in the binned `adult` column you created.  You should just add `dropna=False` to your `pd.crosstab()` command, which will return the right result:

```
pd.crosstab(titanic.survived, titanic.adult, dropna=False, normalize=True, margins=True)

adult   kid     adult       All
survived            
0   0.047619    0.546218    0.616162
1   0.068627    0.337535    0.383838
All 0.116246    0.883754    1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the good tip. I have never imagined that missing values work in such a way.